# URL action generator in Laravel 6.x

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I get a really weird error after I have updated to Laravel 6.4. Have I missed something?

**Doesn't work**

```
{{ action('Admin\OfferController@post', ['id'=>$offer->offer_id,'post'=>0]) }}
```

**Works**

```
{{ action('Admin\OfferController@post', [$offer->offer_id, 0]) }}
```

**Error**

> Missing required parameters for [Route: offers.edit]

Comment: Is `$offer->offer_id` correct? Feels like it should be `$offer->id`. Also, the 1st approach is the correct syntax, the 2nd is not: 
https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-action. Also, post your `route/web.php`; might help if we can see the route.

Comment: The offer_id is fine, I don't use simple id as a field name.

Route: Route::get("offers/post/{id}/{active}", 'OfferController@post');

Method in controller: public function post($id,$post){}

Comment: Ok, no problem; makes sense. The only difference I can see is you're defining an action for `Admin\OfferController@post`, but your route is using `OfferController@post` (no `Admin`). Is that the correct route/controller?

Comment: No that's fine. OK, I figured out. The problem is the second parameter called "active" in the router file. But the name of the second argument in the controller function is "post". But this wasn't a problem so far. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: Ah ok, so the indices in the 2nd argument of `action()` need to match the URL parameter definitions, and not the variable names in the Controller method. Good to know. And no problem! Glad I could help. Feel free to post a self-answer, and you can eventually accept it and close this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 6.3(ish, I think) made the action url generator a little more strict, if you're naming the param (i.e. `'id'=> 0`) then you have to make sure that name matches exactly the name of the param in the route definition.

You can find the name of the param required by using `php artisan route:list` and looking for the route you're trying to post to. In this case I suspect it should be `'offer' => $offer->offer_id` instead of `'id' => $offer->offer_id` but that's only if you generated the route using the route::resource method.

For example. in an app I'm currently working on the I have the following

```php
Route::resource('/articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

Which generates the following route for updating an article

```php
PUT /articles/{article}
```

So to use the action URL generator I have to do the following

```php
action('ArticlesController@update', ['article' => $article->id])
```

The reason your second example works is because, in the absence of you telling it what that first variable is called, the URL generator assumes that the first param satisfies the param needed to generate the route.